# Facebook Marketing API filter ads by action type

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, meteor

I cannot figure out how to filter all ads I retrieve using the Facebook Marketing API inside the url.
I get alls events of an ad account by

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/act_XYZ/adgroups?fields=name,tracking_specs
```

But how do I specify the action.type to only show events with the type "rsvp"?

I tried different methods like

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/act_XYZ/adgroups?fields=name,tracking_specs&tracking_specs={action.type:"rsvpw"}
```

and many other ways but I do always get the same results as using the call without any filter.

I also tried giving the same parameters in side the HTTP Head but did not work either.
What do I need to do in order to get my results filtered by the action type and furthermore the second step would be to also specify the exact event.

I am using Meteor as backend but that should not be a problem since everything I am doing is working.

Just to provide more information how I do the HTTP call.

```
HTTP.call("GET", "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/act_XYZ/adgroups?fields=name,tracking_specs",{
              params: {
                  access_token: Meteor.users.findOne({_id:adaccounts[s].userId}).services.facebook.accessToken
              }
            });
```

This works perfectly with any other API endpoint I am using but I just do not know how to apply the filter. I already use since and until for receiving events.

Comment: Which documentation are you using? Is there actually a filter option for the API?

Comment: I am using the official facebook documentation and they provide examples where they use curl to make calls and filter them by action type.

Comment: Can you link to that documentation please, the one showing filtering when fetching ads from an account? the format of your example doesn't match anything i'm aware of

Comment: How would you filter all ads by action type? For example which call would you make to get all ads with the action type rsvp without using curl of course? Under examples: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/action-specs/v2.4

Comment: Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: The document you linked to does not explain anything about GETting marketing API objects by making a filtered request. I actually don't think you can make Marketing API calls in such a way that the API does the filtering for you; at - like @Igy - least I'm not aware of such a feature.

Comment: Oh sorry you are right it is only for creating. So the best way to search for an ad for an event is to get all ads and search thorugh all of them? That is not very efficient isn't it?